# jQuery UI Slide - Move content during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm building a website which relies on jQuery effects and I have a problem with the jQuery Slide effect.
I'm using that through a `toggle` function for the moment, but that will change in a later stage.

The fact is that I'm hinding an element when a certain action is executed. When you use the function `slide` the content beneath those elements moves when the animation is completed to take up the free space which was created with the effect.

The problem is that the content is only moved as soon as the animation is completed. Is there any way to move the content when the animation is still running. With other words, I want to move the content together with the animation, but I don't want to call the `slide` function on my element that should move with it.

I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg9vL8m/6/

**Edit: Question update and fiddle**

Here's an update to the question, and please see my original updated fiddle.
When you execute the slide effect in jQuery UI, see the bottom example on my fiddle, the box is moved up, and is somewhere placed behind an invisible screen (tough to explain).

With the animate function, see the top example in my fiddle, the area is shrinked, and that's something which I want to avoid. I want to achieve the effect such as 'Slide' does, but the content under the box must move up immediately with the animation, and not after the animation has been completed.

**Edit: Reworked the correct answer in a plugin.**

Thanks to the answers I've received here, I found the correct code, modified a bit, and created a plugin from it which I'll place here.

The plugin is called 'Curtain' and can be described as rising the requested element as a curtain and thus move it out of the way.

Here's the source code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.curtain = function(options, callback) {
        var settings = $.extend( {}, $.fn.curtain.defaults, options);
        var tabContentsHeight = $(this).height();

        $(this).animate({height:0}, settings.duration);
        $(this).children().animate({'margin-top':'-' + tabContentsHeight + 'px'}, settings.duration, function() {
            $(this).css({"margin-top":0});

            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(this);
            }
        });

        return this; // Allows chaining.
    };

    $.fn.curtain.defaults = {
        duration: 250
    };
}(jQuery));
```

The plugin can be called like this:

```
element.curtain({ duration: 250 }, function() {
    // Callback function goes here.
});
```

If someone has remarks or a better way to solve this problem, please share it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the animate function like this:

```
$('#square').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $(this).animate({height:-200},2500);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg9vL8m/3/)

Updated code to create a "curtain raising" like animation:-

```
$('#square').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $(this).animate({height:-200},2500);
    $(this).children().animate({"margin-top":"-400px"},2500, function() {
        $(this).css({"margin-top":0})
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
`#square{
     overflow:hidden;
 }`
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg9vL8m/10/)

Comment: Sorry but after further investigation. It isn't really, what I needed. Because the bottom dissapears until it reaches the top. I want to object to move out. So grab the bottom and move it up, until it reaches the top. The same as what the slide effect does.

Comment: Got it. You want animation from bottom to top. I'll update my code by making the changes.

Comment: Could you check my updated question and fiddle, that should make it more clear.

Comment: Almost, but you still see a difference between the jQuery UI slide method and your implementation. I don't want to be rude, it's great what you do, but I try to remake a Windows Application for the Web and the animations must be exactely the same. Have you an idea on how to update your code so that it's working exactely the same as jQuery UI slide function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg9vL8m/10/). By changing the value of decrease in "margin-top" to get something similar like slide-up. To incorporate the delay between the line of the function I have increased the speed of margin-top change. Otherwise I think by CSS3 transitions we can get exactly something like jQuery UI Slide.

Comment: Hereby I grant you the title of jQuery Guru. Thanks, this solution is exactely whay I need. But what do you mean with the CSS3 transistions, I don't get it since this is what I need. Anyway, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Complexity Thanks for the compliment. :) By CSS3 transitions we can also create similar animations like this one but disadvantage is that some old browsers doesn't support it. You have to install modernizr plugin to run it in old browsers.

Comment: Ok, that makes it clear, but I don't want to do that. Let's stick with jQuery. I'll try to understand your code later today and create a plugin from it called 'RaiseCurtain' or something so it will be re-usable code. I'll update my original question, with my version of the plugin just to make it easy for other users aswell.

Comment: The plugin has been created. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/6Lg9vL8m/1/) is the effect you wanted?

```
$('#square').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).animate({height :0},2500 );
});
```

Comment: Sorry but after further investigation. It isn't really, what I needed. Because the bottom dissapears until it reaches the top. I want to object to move out. So grab the bottom and move it up, until it reaches the top. The same as what the slide effect does.

Comment: Sry, still not sure what exactly you want.

Comment: @Complexity can you to edit your question to clear up this confusion, I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to object to move out".  Thanks

Comment: Could you check my updated question and fiddle, that should make it more clear.